# owl carousel with popop for youtube video keeps items moving when popup is close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousal to show youtube videos and when use click on the video it show video in nivo lightbox `$('a').nivoLightbox();`

Which all works fine but the problem i am facing is that when i close the popup this particular carousal  keep moving item left or right based on the mouse position on any part of page.

i am not sure how unbind mouse with owl i tried few thing that didnt work such as `$("owl-carousel").trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');`

Any thing else i can do to stop move from scrolling items left right

```
$("#content-slide-videos").owlCarousel({
        //autoPlay: 5000, Set AutoPlay to 5 seconds
        items: 3,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
        itemsTablet: [768, 2],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        pagination: false,
        dots: false,
        //video:true,
       // autoplayHoverPause: false,
        lazyLoad: true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: [
            "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa pe-7s-angle-right'></i>"
        ],
        afterInit: function (elem) {
            var that = this;
            that.owlControls.prependTo(elem);
        }
    });
```

Solved the issue, I was using by using js file from https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/669264/owl.carousel.js

not sure what could be the problem while both files are v1.3.3 after comparing both file only different was `'use strict';` line was not present in the other file.

Comment: Can you create a **working** snippet for this?

Comment: I have setup the fiddle, but it is working fine on fiddle it seems some other JS or plugin is creating some sort of issue. not sure which one?

Comment: i think issue is with "owl-wrapper grabbing" when i click `owl-wrapper` class changes to `owl-wrapper grabbing` and stays like that even when i close popup & it is not only due to popup even i click on date or some other part if keeps doing that

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it 

Comment: Vimeo Not loading if any possible to play vimeo Videos